# IP routing for multihomed machine

Tags: windows, routes, iptables

I have configured my machine to have two IPs on the same NIC with different gateways. Everything works fine, it reroutes automatically if one interface is unable to ping (the other interface is able to connect automatically)

Config:

192.168.1.2 is my primary ip with gateway as 192.168.1.1
172.169.1.2 is my secondary ip with gateway as 172.169.1.1

Now how do I make my machine to choose the exact interface using IP routing .

say I want to access 192.168.1.6 using 192.168.1.2 interface alone. By this I mean, 192.168.1.6 shouldn't know that my IP is 172.169.1.2

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.   You could simply implement a dynamic routing protocol like OSPF if your gateways support it.. Alternatively,  and what is likely the better solution, is to use two different subnets.  If both IP addrs on your nic are in the same net,  you have no control over where your traffic is sourced from.